# Varying symbology by two fields of attribute table in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, fields-attributes

I got a point layer and my task is to visualize it according to two (2) values of its attribute table at the same time: each point (a) has to be presented as graduated symbol size (manual classification of 5 classes) according to the values of field "A", and at the same time each point (b) has to be colored with graduated colors (equal interval classification of 4 or 5 classes) according to field "B".

I tried in ArcGIS 10.8.x.. Symbology > Multiple attributes > Quantities by category : I never manage to get the correct color according to equal interval classification of field "B" values. The size of field "A" is always correct but the color, according to the values of field "B", is never correct. NEVER.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a new attribute field to your point file to hold the hard-coded classification of variable B. It will have values 1 through 5. I would then symbolize this layer by color: Symbology-->Quanties-->Graduate Colors. Then create 5 versions of this layer (Copy-->Paste * 5) and use a definition query for each of the copies, one for each class of variable B. Then just change the size of the points for each layer/class. In the Symbology tab, right-click Symbol-->Properties for all Symbols, and change the point size for each color.